# Definable sets in a $\kappa$-saturated structure.

Tags: model-theory

Exercise 5.2.4. in Ziegler, Tent: A Course in Model Theory states:

> If (the $L$-structure) $\mathfrak{A}$ is $\kappa$-saturated, then all definable subsets are either finite or have cardinality at least $\kappa$.

This statement seems only correct, if $|\mathfrak{A}|\geq\kappa$, as the set $A$ defined by $\top$ could otherwise have a cardinality $\aleph_0\leq|A|<\kappa$ for $\kappa>\aleph_0$.

I didn't manage to come up with a viable idea for proofing the statement. I would be thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 3):

A $\kappa$-saturated structure has cardinality at least $\kappa$: otherwise, consider $\{x\not=a: a\in\mathfrak{A}\}$ ... *(Fine, unless it's finite.)*

So the situation you're envisioning can't occur.

EDIT: And indeed, as Alex observes below, this should be thought of as a hint to the whole problem.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifed the statement for me.
My question - as initially stated - was not clearly formulated: I also was asking for hints proofing the statement.

Comment: @Dalhamun You could view Noah's answer as a significant hint to proving the statement in general. The partial type $\{x\neq a : a\in \mathfrak{A}\}$ says that $x$ is not equal to any element of the definable set defined by $\top$...

Comment: Small correction: a $\kappa$-saturated structure has cardinality at least $\kappa$, *unless it is finite*.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan Bah. Fixed!

Comment: I came up with following reasoning: For a definable set $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$(for formula $\varphi$) we have either $|\varphi(\mathfrak{A})|=|\neg\varphi(\mathfrak{A})|\geq\kappa$ or $|\varphi(\mathfrak{A})|<\kappa\leq|\neg\varphi(\mathfrak{A})|$. The first case is trivial, in the scond case we note that the sub-Stone space $[\varphi(x)]=\bigcup_{a\in\varphi(\mathfrak{A})}[x\dot{=}a]\subset S_1(\varphi(\mathfrak{A}))$ only consists of isolated types. Since $\mathfrak{A}$ is $\kappa$-saturated, a definable set can be finitely covered by these iso.types: $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$ must be finite.

Comment: More precise: Since $\mathfrak{A}$ is $\kappa$-saturated, a definable set of cardinality less than $\kappa$(as $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$ is), can be finitely covered by the isolated types $\langle a\dot{=}x\rangle\in S_1(\varphi(\mathfrak{A}))$.

Comment: @Dalhamun What you wrote makes almost no sense to me. Why should $[\varphi(x)]$ consist only of isolated types?

Comment: @Dalhamun just look at the partial type $\{\varphi(x)\}\cup\{x\neq a \mid a\in \varphi(\mathfrak{A})\}$! Is it realized in $\mathfrak{A}$?

Comment: @Alex: I was thinking that since $[\varphi(x)]=\bigcup_{a\in\varphi(\mathfrak{A})}[x\dot{=}a]$ and $[x\dot{=}a]=\{\text{tp}(a/x\dot{=}a)\}=\{\langle x\dot{=}a\rangle\}$ for $a\in \varphi(\mathfrak{A})$, so every element in $[\varphi(x)]\subseteq S_1(\varphi(\mathfrak{A}))$ is an isolated type. If that reasoning is wrong, can you give me a counter example?

Comment: @Alex: $\{\varphi(x)\}\cup\{\neg x\dot{=}a\;|\;a\in\varphi(\mathfrak{A})\}$ is not realised in $\mathfrak{A}$. Are you pointing to some compactness argument?

Comment: @Alex: Next try: Assume again $|\varphi(\mathfrak{A})|<\kappa$. If $\{\varphi(x)\}\cup\{\neg x\dot{=}a\;|\;a\in\varphi(\mathfrak{A})\}$ would be consistent with Th$(\mathfrak{A}_{\varphi(\mathfrak{A})})$, then any type $p(x)\supseteq\{\varphi(x)\}\cup\{\neg x\dot{=}a\;|\;a\in\varphi(\mathfrak{A})\}$ over $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$ would be realized in $\mathfrak{A}$, which cannot be the case. This implies that $\{\varphi(x)\}\cup\{\neg x\dot{=}a\;|\;a\in\varphi(\mathfrak{A})\}$ must be inconsistent, which can only the case if $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$ is finite.

Comment: @Dalhamun Yes, that's the argument I had in mind. Regarding your previous argument, I think I understand what you meant now. $[\varphi(x)] = \bigcup_{a\in \varphi(\mathfrak{A})}[x=a]$, because any type in $S(\varphi(\mathfrak{A}))$ which contains $\varphi(x)$ is realized in $\varphi(\mathfrak{A})$ by $\kappa$-compactness. Is that right? The second argument is really just a rephrasing of this, which I think is a bit clearer.